# Flick an image left or right

Tags: unity-game-engine, 2d

Trying to make a function which makes the user able to swipe an photo to left or right.

If any of you might be able to help me, it would really be appreciated.

Comment: Flagging for removal for 'too broad'

Comment: Sure, just make a method 
void DetectSwipe() {
    if (DidSwipeLeft()) {
       SwipeLeft();
    } else if (DidSwipeRight()) {
       SwipeRight();
    }
}